# git push to remote does not terminate

Tags: node.js, bash, git, npm, git-post-receive

I want to push local changes to a live server, but the 'git-push' command does not terminate, after doing its' job. The program has to be stopped manually (I would like it to close itself).

I'm trying to use the git post-receive hook to update the live server and to restart two daemons. The problem is that the 'npm start' (the last command) continues to send its text output to 'git-push', even though 'npm start' was started as a background job. I've tried to redirect the stdin and sterr to /dev/null, but that didn't yield any result.

The 'npm start' starts a react web app

```
#!/bin/sh
killall node
GIT_WORK_TREE=/root/danskesn git checkout -f
server="node /root/danskesn/server/server.js"
webapp="npm start 1>/dev/null 2>&1 &"

nohup $server &
nohup $webapp &
```

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that the files that you are trying to update are being locked by your active (react web app) process and therefore the git push does not get a chance to resolve properly.

Answer (score 0):

Note carefully the redirections in this line:

> ```
> webapp="npm start 1>/dev/null 2>&1 &"
> ```

Now look at the two backgrounded processes:

> ```
> nohup $server &
> nohup $webapp &
> ```

One of these—the one using `$webapp`—has embedded redirections for stdout and stderr.  But what is `$server` set to?

> ```
> server="node /root/danskesn/server/server.js"
> ```

Exercise:  Are there any redirections here?  If so, find them.  (There *could* be some, inside `node` or `/root/danskesn/server/server.js`.  I don't believe there are, though.)

If there *aren't* any redirections, the standard output and standard error output from this `nohup $server &` command is still connected to the `git push` command across your network.  Your `git push` will wait for any output, and copy it to your shell session, prefixed with the word `remote:`.  Your `git push` will terminate only when there is no more output available, i.e., when `nohup $server &` has closed its output and error streams, probably by terminating entirely.